# Java No class Def Found Error in Android studio even after Clean

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I've been developing a Pacman clone and i am generating a maze with the following class : it worked fine on netbeans but when i tried importing it to Android studio so i can use it with LibGDX it gives me some errors here they are :S :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 187
Process: com.fistbump.patman.android, PID: 2221
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.patman.mazegeneration.Maze2D$Node$2
at com.patman.mazegeneration.Maze2D$Node.getNeighbours(Maze2D.java:197)
at com.patman.mazegeneration.Maze2D$Node.linkRandomUnlinkedNeighbour(Maze2D.java:176)
at com.patman.mazegeneration.Maze2D$Maze.growMaze(Maze2D.java:125)
at com.patman.mazegeneration.Maze2D$Maze.<init>(Maze2D.java:95)
at com.patman.mazegeneration.Maze2D.<init>(Maze2D.java:33)
at com.fistbump.patman.MyGdxGame.create(MyGdxGame.java:25)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:243)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1519)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
package com.patman.mazegeneration;
```

And the Code is :

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.function.Predicate;


public class Maze2D {

private BufferedImage im;

public BufferedImage getIm() {
return im;
}

public void setIm(BufferedImage im) {
this.im = im;
}

public Maze2D(int x, int y) {

new Maze(x, y);

}

public static final class Coordinate2D {
private final Maze maze;
private final int x, y;

public Coordinate2D(Maze maze, int x, int y) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(maze);
    if (x < 0 || x >= maze.xSize || y < 0 || y >= maze.ySize)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    this.maze = maze;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(maze, x, y);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object another) {
    if (!(another instanceof Coordinate2D)) return false;
    Coordinate2D c4d = (Coordinate2D) another;
    return maze == c4d.maze && x == c4d.x && y == c4d.y;
}


public Coordinate2D minusX() {
    return x == 0 ? null : new Coordinate2D(maze, x - 1, y);
}

public Coordinate2D plusX() {
    return x == maze.xSize - 1 ? null : new Coordinate2D(maze, x + 1, y);
}

public Coordinate2D minusY() {
    return y == 0 ? null : new Coordinate2D(maze, x, y - 1);
}

public Coordinate2D plusY() {
    return y == maze.ySize - 1 ? null : new Coordinate2D(maze, x, y + 1);
}

public Maze getMaze() {
    return maze;
}
}

public final class Maze {
private final int xSize, ySize;
private final Map<Coordinate2D, Node> nodes;
private final Node start;

public Maze(int x, int y) {
    this.xSize = x;
    this.ySize = y;
    nodes = new HashMap<>(x * y);
    fill();
    this.start = chooseRandomNode();
    growMaze();
    im = draw();
}

private void fill() {
    for (int b = 0; b < xSize; b++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < ySize; c++) {
            Coordinate2D coord = new Coordinate2D(this, b, c);
            nodes.put(coord, new Node(coord));
        }
    }
}

public Node nodeAt(Coordinate2D coord) {
    if (coord == null) return null;
    return nodes.get(coord);
}

private Node chooseRandomNode() {
    int n = (int) (Math.random() * xSize * ySize);
    return new ArrayList<>(nodes.values()).get(n);
}

private void growMaze() {
    List<Node> frontier = new ArrayList<>(xSize * ySize);
    frontier.add(start);
    start.linked = true;
    while (!frontier.isEmpty()) {
        Collections.shuffle(frontier);
        Node n = frontier.get(0);
        Node next = n.linkRandomUnlinkedNeighbour();
        if (next != null) {
            frontier.add(next);
        } else {
            frontier.remove(0);
        }
    }
}

public BufferedImage draw() {
    int cellWidth = 40;
    int cellHeight = 40;
    int boardWidth = cellWidth * (xSize + 1);
    int boardHeight = cellHeight * (ySize + 1);
    BufferedImage im = new BufferedImage(boardWidth + cellWidth, boardHeight + cellHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g = im.createGraphics();
    g.setPaint(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    g.fillRect(0, 0, im.getWidth(), im.getHeight());
    for (int x = 0; x < xSize; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < ySize; y++) {
            Coordinate2D c = new Coordinate2D(this, x, y);
            Node n = nodeAt(c);
            int x1 = cellWidth * x + cellWidth - 1;
            int y1 = cellHeight * y + cellHeight - 1;
            int x2 = x1 + cellWidth;
            int y2 = y1 + cellHeight;
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(20));
            if (!n.isLinkedTo(n.minusY())) g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y1);
            if (!n.isLinkedTo(n.plusY())) g.drawLine(x1, y2, x2, y2);
            if (!n.isLinkedTo(n.minusX())) g.drawLine(x1, y1, x1, y2);
            if (!n.isLinkedTo(n.plusX())) g.drawLine(x2, y1, x2, y2);
        }
    }
    return im;
}
}

private class Node {
    private final Coordinate2D coord;
    private final List<Node> linkedNeighbours;
    private List<Node> neighbours;
    private boolean linked;

    public Node(Coordinate2D coord) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(coord);
        this.coord = coord;
        linkedNeighbours = new ArrayList<>(8);
    }

    public Node linkRandomUnlinkedNeighbour() {
        List<Node> list = new ArrayList<>(getNeighbours());
        list.removeIf(new Predicate<Node>() {
            @Override
            public boolean test(Node n) {
                return n.linked;
            }
        });
        if (list.isEmpty()) return null;
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        Node next = list.get(0);
        next.getNeighbours();
        linkedNeighbours.add(next);
        next.linkedNeighbours.add(this);
        next.linked = true;
        return next;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("ReturnOfCollectionOrArrayField")
    public List<Node> getNeighbours() {
        if (neighbours == null) {
            List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(minusX(), plusX(),  minusY(), plusY()));
            nodes.removeIf(new Predicate<Node>() {
                @Override
                public boolean test(Node x) {
                    return x == null;
                }
            });
            neighbours = Collections.unmodifiableList(nodes);
        }
        return neighbours;
    }


    public boolean isLinkedTo(Node node) {
       return linkedNeighbours.contains(node);
    }

    public Maze getMaze() {
       return coord.getMaze();
    }

    public Node minusX() {
        return getMaze().nodeAt(coord.minusX());
    }

    public Node plusX() {
        return getMaze().nodeAt(coord.plusX());
    }

    public Node minusY() {
        return getMaze().nodeAt(coord.minusY());
    }

    public Node plusY() {
        return getMaze().nodeAt(coord.plusY());
    }
}
```

I tried cleaning and rebuilding the project but it was no good 
Really thankful in advance

Comment: can to put your complete log ?

Comment: becuase the class is not on classpath.

Comment: @ShvetChakra Sorry i forgot it , done now

Comment: @pmverma it's a normal subclass . how can i put it in the classpath

Comment: @GehadGamal If your libGDX has jars then `RIghtClickOnProject -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries tab -> Add jars or Add external jar, select libGDX jar and click OK`.

Comment: i tried that, nothing happened. also it is good to know that i am using a libGDX generated project so it already had its jars . also that Class Maze2D has an internal class Node .. its a class that is written i am not using an external Jar file for that